# What is the process behind this output?

Tags: c

The value of `i` is 2 when I comment out statements 2 and 3, but when I don't, `i` becomes 3. Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a[5]={5,1,15,20,25};
  int i,j,k=1,m;
  i=++a[1];   //Statement 1               
  j=a[1]++;   //Statement 2
  m=a[i++];   //Statement 3

  printf("%d %d %d",i,j,m);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because with Statement 2+3, it´s different code? What do you not understand?

Comment: Because statement 3 increments `i`.

Comment: Try explaining why you expect what you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Statement 3, your code is incrementing the value of `i`:

```
m = a[i++];
```

This is easier to notice is you break it up as the following two lines:

```
m = a[i];
i++;
```

Note: The order is important! Since this is post-increment (`i++`, not `++i`), the value of `i` is used first, and then incremented.

Comment: Understood , the lesson that i learned is that i gets used first and then incremented.

Comment: in j=a[1]++ ,does a[1] is first assigned and then incremented or first it is incremented then assigned

Comment: `j = a[1]++;` is the same as `j = a[1];`, followed by `a[1]++;`.

Answer (score 0):

`m=a[i++]` causes `i` to be incremented by one.  It is the `i++` part that increments `i`.

Comment: I think i got it , but then the output of the m should be 20 right , but the output is showing 15 or does it get incremented later , please explain the process ?

Comment: Yes, it is incremented later. `i++` uses `i`, then increments. `++i` increments, then uses `i`.

Answer (score 0):

after `statement 1: i = a[1] + 1` which means you are adding 1 to `a[1]` then storing that value in i

```
i = 2 ; a[1] = 2'
```

after `statement 2: j = a[1]++` which means you are adding 1 to `a[1]` i.e `2 + 1`

```
j = 2; a[1] = 3;
```

after `statement 3: m = a[i + 1]` which means you are adding 1 to the index value
i already equals 2 so you do `m = a[2+1]` which is `15` but since you have `i++` that operation still preforms the add to `i` making `i =4`

```
m = 15; i = 4; thus a[i] = 20
```